# ClearLayer() not working for polyline Decorators

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with leaflet api, where user draw shapes on images.

> Clearly i am having problem with polyline decorator because clearlayer
>   method doesn't seem to work for decorators, might be a bug or owner
>   haven't implemented it yet.

When i try to clear layers, it give console error

**Console Error**

> Uncaught TypeError: layer.off is not a function

**Script**

```
L.easyButton('<img src="ex.png">', function () {
                    map.on('click', polylineFence1);
                }).addTo(map);
// Add coordinate to the polyline
                var polylineFence1 = new L.Polyline([], { color: 'red' });
                function fencePlace1(e) {
                    myCheck = "wire";
                    // Add coordinate to the polyline
                    polylineFence1.addLatLng(e.latlng).addTo(currentFeatureGroup);
                    var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polylineFence1, {
                        patterns: [
                            // define a pattern of 10px-wide dashes, repeated every 20px on the line
                            { offset: 5, repeat: '10px', symbol: new L.Symbol.marker() }
                        ]
                    }).addTo(currentFeatureGroup);
                    }

          //clear layer
                L.easyButton('<img src="/assets/img/delete.png">', function () {
                    currentFeatureGroup.clearLayers();
                }).addTo(map);
```

If someone have any idea how to resolve it,please help...Thanks for your time

Comment: In which line exactly do you get the error? `layer.off` is for removing event listeners from layers. Maybe it's called during the clearLayers() function - I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Krxldfx Thanks for reply,I have raised the issue at https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator/issues/17 , its marked as bug from owner.....